# Spring platform bom for Gradle multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I've a multiple module gradle project.

Root has the following modules : core, app (dependent on core), web(dependent on app,core)

From  https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management

I have used

```
 plugins {  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.4.RELEASE" }

 dependencyManagement {
  imports { 
     mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:+' // 2.0.1.RELEASE
   }
  }
```

inside the build.gradle of core.

When I triggered

```
 gradle clean build
```

from root command prompt, core jar was built successfully, but app **failed** to resolve the versions of the dependencies.

**common.gradle**  in root directory

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/" }
    // mavenLocal()
}
```

**build.gradle** of Core

```
plugins {
   id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.4.RELEASE"
}

apply from: '../common.gradle'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencyManagement {
   imports {
    mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:+' // 2.0.1.RELEASE
    }
 }

dependencies {
  compile  'javax.jms:javax.jms-api:+' //2.0
  compile  'javax.mail:mail:+' //1.4.6
  compile  'javax.validation:validation-api' //1.0.0.GA
  compile  'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap' //4.0.1.RELEASE
  compile  'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'  //1.9.1.RELEASE
  compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:+' //1.0.0.Final    
 }
```

**build.gradle** for app module

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: '../common.gradle'
dependencies {
compile project(':Core')
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator' //5.1.1.Final
compile 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache'   //2.9.1
compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms' //4.2.3.RELEASE
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-oxm' //3.0.4.RELEASE }
```

**Error message** snippet:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:compile'.

  > Could not find org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator//hibernate-validator-.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator//hibernate-validator-.jar
  >     http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator//hibernate-validator-.pom
  >     http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator//hibernate-validator-.jar
  >   Required by:
  >     Root:app:unspecified

**Environment** :

D:\personal>gradle -v

---

### Gradle 2.9

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

JVM:          1.8.0_20 (Oracle Corporation 25.20-b23)

OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the dependency management plugin to the app module. Right now it's only available in the core module, but you are trying to use it's features in the app module.
It's probably a good idea to apply the plugin to every module. If you want you can add this to your root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.4.RELEASE" }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
}
```

Answer to the comment:
Artifacts require explicit version when they are not part of the [platform-bom](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions). You can declare your own dependencies and use them without explicit version:

```
dependencyManagement {
     dependencies {
          dependency 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.3.RELEASE'
          dependency group:'commons-logging', name:'commons-logging', version:'1.1.2'
     }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
}
```

source: [plugin documentation](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin)

Comment: Thank a ton for your answer. One question : Why Gradle is asking for the explicit version for some Artifacts like 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api,  javax.mail:mail etc. ?